# How to upload an image along with a text to a database using php-Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to upload an image along with a text to a Mysql db. Currently, my image is uploaded but the text is not submitted to the db_table along with image. Am testing this through postman, and I get the following lines of error:

1. **Warning**: Illegal string offset 'image_text' in
   **C:\xampp\htdocs\iroamnetapi\upload.php** on line **17**
2. **Notice**: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in
   **C:\xampp\htdocs\iroamnetapi\upload.php** on line **17**

Here is the code of what I have tried in my upload.php file:
[image]

And my database looks like this:

[image]

What can I do to make the text submit along with the image?

Comment: please check  $_POST is empty or not. @line 8 var_dump($_POST) . And check the result

Comment: please check are you sending any parameter names as `image_text` you can `var_dump` it or check `echo isset($_POST['image_text'])`

Comment: check $_POST['image_text'] as @AshickurRahman said

Comment: did you tried this way?
$mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'password', 'database');
$mysqli->set_charset('charset');

$string = $mysqli->real_escape_string($string);
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES ('$string')");